# Why is the hits.transaction id null in BigQuery?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am currently attempting to work on a client report in BigQuery and have a question regarding the hits.transaction id cell in BigQuery. For our client, transaction ID is captured in the e-comm transactions data. Specifically, in Google Analytics, we can see this by going to "goals/ecomm" > "ecomm" > "transaction list". Furthermore, within the Google Analytics API, this dimension is called ga:transactionId.

The problem is, when I look in BigQuery, hits.transaction id looks to be null when it seems like it should be populated. Is this an error? If it is not, what is the corresponding dimension in BigQuery for transactionID?

Comment: Asking someone who has worked on the Google Analytics / BigQuery integration. Will post back when I hear from them.

Comment: Great. Thanks Jordan. Appreciate you taking the time. Keep me posted.

Comment: 6 years later I come across the same problem and can't access a solution because the link from the approved answer doesn't work properly anymore. Can you please post the answer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you post this to the Google Analytics / BigQuery Developers group (designed for developers and analysts that are using that specific integration). You can find information about it here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437706

Alternatively, you can contact your Google Analytics Premium support team for specific questions about your data.

To specifically answer your question, the eCommerce transaction IDs are found in
hits.transaction.transactionId and hits.item.transactionId for hits.type of TRANSACTION and ITEM. The full schema is here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719

Comment: Great. I will definitely post this on GA / BQ Developers group. That said, thank you for the specific answer.

Comment: However, for enhanced e-commerce implementations, there are no TRANSACTION or ITEM hits, so where can the Transaction ID be found? It appears in the GA Analytics Sales Performance report, but not in BigQuery.

Comment: The first link no longer works. It leads to a general page that is not useful for this case.